# Given $x''+x'+x+2x^3=0$. Prove that any solution can be extended to the entire line.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Given $x''+x'+x+2x^3=0$. Prove that any solution can be extended to the entire line.

I think maybe multiply $x'$ both side of the equation is useful. But I can not handle the $x'^2$

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the term 'extended over the entire line'?

Comment: I mean that the solution exists when $t\in(-\infty,\infty)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that idea was correct. You find an energy functional
$$
E(x,x')=\frac12(x'^2+x^2+x^4)
$$
with
$$
\frac{d}{dt}E(x,x')=-x'^2
$$
so that in forward time the solution will cross the energy levels downwards towards the minimum at $x=x'=0$.

In the other time direction one finds increasing energy levels, however the increase is linearly bounded
$$
|e'|\le x'^2\le 2e,~~~~e(t)=E(x(t),x'(t))
$$
so that you still get à la Grönwall $e(t)\le e(0)e^{2|t|}$. This bound shows that there is no divergence to infinity in finite time, so that the solution also exists everywhere on the negative time half-axis.